# How to re-enable a disabled JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So there will be a text field that I disable using the `textField.setEnabled(false)` method. However later on in the code I want to enable this text field back again. `textField.setEnabled(true)` does not work at this moment.

How should I address this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If the textField.setEnable(true) statement doesn't work then your textField variable does not reference the text field that is visible on the frame. So maybe you defined the variable twice, once as a local variable and once as an instance variable.

Comment: @camickr I will check on that

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a Jtextfield like instance variables